# Missing data in response json results

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I am testing the google drive api V3 files.list method after testing the API on the Google site

[Try me](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) I received the expected results.

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "nextPageToken": "~!!~AI9......",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1HL...",
   "name": "Slack Channel DLs",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
   "teamDriveId": "0AD...",
   "driveId": "0AD..."
  }]
}
```

But when using python I am missing this part:

```
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "nextPageToken": "~!!~AI9......",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files":
```

This is my code:

```
import json


from main_methods import GdriveConnection
# mainmethods is a script for my methods.

googleDrive = GdriveConnection()


files = googleDrive.listFiles()

print(json.dumps(files, indent=2))
count = 0

for file in files:
    count = count + 1

print('\n Total files: ' + str(count))
```

Result:

```
[
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1HL...",
   "name": "Slack Channel DLs",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
   "teamDriveId": "0AD...",
   "driveId": "0AD..."
  }]
```

method GdriveConnection()

```
    def listFiles(self):
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=self.creds)

        results = service.files().list(corpora='user', includeItemsFromAllDrives='true', orderBy='folder', pageSize='1000', supportsAllDrives='true', supportsTeamDrives='true').execute()

        files = results.get('files', [])

        return(files)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

`files = results.get('files', [])` returns the `files` object of the whole response, which should be in `results` on the previous line.

To print the whole response, return `results` instead of `files`.

**Reference:**

[get() function in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp)